# apache php-fpm: How to run scripts on same domain w/ different users

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, php-fpm, php5

I have a number of directories containing php scripts that need to be run as separate users.

Example directory structure is as follows:

```
/var/www
├── project
│   ├── item1
│   │   └── script1.php
│   ├── item2
│   │   └── script2.php
│   └── index.php
```

I can run them as separate pools by using separate virtualhosts. Where foo.com -> item1 and bar.com -> item2

i.e.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName foo.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/project/item1

  ...

  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
    Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-item1
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-item1 -socket /var/run/php5-fpm-item1.sock -pass-header Authorization
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

However, I need to access them as foobar.com/item1 foobar.com/item2. Or even as foobar.com/item1 which executes item2, each as different users. Any ideas?

Any help, greatly appreciated.